# On selction of cell, redirect to another sheet in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to know if it is feasible or not. If I select a cell in excel(sheet1) it will redirect me to sheet2 which has the relevant data the cell I selected in sheet1.

Comment: You can use a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Two method:

---

**1) Hyperlink (the easy way)**

Right click on the cell and choose "Hyperlink" at the bottom of the context menu

In the window that pops up, click on "Place In This Document" on the left

Select the sheet you want and type the cell reference along the top

Click OK to add your hyperlink

[image: Screenshot]

---

**2) VBA (the hard way)**

Drop the code below into the worksheets module in VBA

Modify the range and sheet name references per your need

Make sure to save the file as a macro-enable file (XLSM or XLSB)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Application.Goto Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1"), True
End Sub
```